# Unable to change graph object title from android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to post a graph object on my facebook timeline, the title and description aren't showing , this is the code below. Any suggestions ?

```
    Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
    postParams.putString("offer", "http://namespace.com/app/myobject.html");
    postParams.putBoolean("fb:explicitly_shared", true);
    postParams.putString("image", _offer.getImgpath());
    postParams.putString("title", _offer.getName());
    postParams.putString("description",_offer.getDescription());

    Request request = new Request(session, "me/namespace:share", postParams, 
                          HttpMethod.POST, callback);

    RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
    task.execute();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

image/title/description are all properties of the OG object, and cannot be specified by parameters to a request. They must be defined via the "og:*" meta properties at the url endpoint (which would be http://namespace.com/app/myobject.html in your example).